# Any finite-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space is closed: easier proof?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

A noted theorem is that a finite-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space must be topologically closed. I have seen some proofs of this theorem which are less simple than this, but what is wrong with the following: let $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$ be a basis for the subspace, then any sequence $x_m$ of points in the subspace induces sequences on each of the coefficients in the expansion: $x_m = a_1^nv_1 + \dotsb + a_n^mv_n$. Then show that the limit of $x_m$ just corresponds to $a_1^* v_1 + \dotsb + a_n^*v_n$, i.e. the limits of the coefficients, which is clearly in the subspace.

Doesn't this work? It seems a lot simpler.

Comment: I think it might be OK if you choose an orthonormal basis for the finite dimensional subspace. If you don't, then how would you justify that each sequence of coefficients of $v_i$  converges? ( I mean it can be done, but it needs some work).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Even minus the orthonormality, the projection operator should be continuous, ensuring the convergence of the sequence, right?

Comment: Well, it is true that each projection is continuous, but I still maintain that it takes more work to prove it.

Comment: Without orthogonality, what is "the" projection operator?

Comment: @NateEldredge The projection onto $v_i$ along $v_1,\dotsc, \hat{v}_i, \dotsc, v_n$.